# In the Visual Studio editor is there a keyboard command to jump to the matching bracket?

Tags: visual-studio, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

In Vi / Vim you can move to a bracket and press <kbd>%</kbd> and the editor would move the cursor to the matching bracket. This saved large amounts of time when moving around the large files in the editor. Is there a Visual Studio equivalent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a keyboard binding `Edit.GotoBrace` which will do what you need.
The [default binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xte2hh6a(VS.71).aspx#vxurfvisualstudio70defaultshortcutkeystextnavigationanchor1) is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>, which you can change here:

> Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd> to move to the matching bracket.