# How to jump to matching #if/#elif/#endif statements?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual C++ 6.0 (1998 vintage), there is a useful command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to cycle through paired conditional statements, jumping from one to the next:

```
#if 
...
#elif 
...
#endif
```

I can't find an equivalent keyboard command to do this in Visual Studio 2010. Anyone know if it's possible?

Note: it is used in an .rc2 file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)

Comment: We'll I'll be darned... the Ctrl-] key does indeed jump forward from the '#if' to the '#elif' etc. I never thought to try it :o) That's exactly what I'm looking for. There's no way to go backward, only forward, although it wraps around when it reaches the #endif. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a command called Edit.GoToBrace and you can change the keyboard shortcut from the Tools. See this [In the Visual Studio editor is there a keyboard command to jump to the matching bracket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743762/in-the-visual-studio-editor-is-there-a-keyboard-command-to-jump-to-the-matching-b).